# Entity Framework 4 - Refresh model really slow

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with Entity Framework. It's really slow to refresh the model (it takes about 15 minutes) after I done a database change.

The model isn't that big (about 50 entities) but one of the entities is large (about 250 properties). I guess the problem is that large entity (in another project I have a model with more entities and no problem at all).

Is there a way to refresh the model and exclude the large entity (only include it when needed)?
Or do you have another idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Found this:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60923

Comment: are u using all of the entity properties?

Comment: Can you validate that it is really problem of the big entity? What happens if you try it in another project with the same database - once with the big entity and once without? Btw. entity with 250 properties is insane.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that table. Now I'm even more confused because I don't know that the problem is. Do you know if there is some kind of log file that I could step through to find which tasks takes such a long time. Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I haven't hear about this behavior before.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka  Thanks! What is the "normal" behavior? How long does it take to refresh 50 entities (we use MySql)? In another project I have it takes about 3 minutes.

Comment: I would start SQL Profiler in SQL Server Management Studio.  That might give you a bit more info.

Comment: I use MySql so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for med:

It seems that the MySql .Net Connector 6.3.5 has a bug.
It threats Timestamp in an incorrect way. When creating the Entity model TimeStamp properties are matched with a DateTimeOffset.

When I updated to the .Net Connector to 6.4.4 I had to change all the DateTimeOffset to DateTime.
After that the refresh of the model only took about 20 seconds.

I hope this will help someone else too.